# Forum Not Redisplaying After Refresh

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a login page that incorporates MySQL. If the user enters the correct information, it will take them to another page, however, if they do not put in the correct information then the page should refresh with the error at the top. Currently, my code is refreshing the page with the error on top but without the forum to log in. I have no idea what is wrong with it...

```
<?php
define("HOST", "localhost"); // The host you want to connect to.
define("USER", "root"); // The database username.
define("PASSWORD", "root"); // The database password. 
define("DATABASE", "dfa24"); // The database name.
session_start(); 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){ 

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE)
or die("Failed to connect");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Phoenix');
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Member WHERE loginName = '".$username."' AND password ='".$password. "'"; //checks for user in database
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error); //shoots an error if something is wrong
    if($result->num_rows < 1) // if the username/password is incorrect then an error message appears
{
    echo "Invalid username/password combination. Please try again.";
    $_SESSION['logged'] = '0';
}
else
{

    $_SESSION['logged']='1';
    $sql = " INSERT INTO Login (loginName,loginTime, loggedIn) 
       VALUES ('$username', NOW(), '1' ) "; // creates the login time.
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die ($mysqli->error); // shoots an error if i did something wrong.
    $_SESSION['logname'] = $userlogin;
    header("Location: MemberHomeScreen.php");
    exit();
}
} else{

$x = false;
$defaults = array("username" => "", "password" => "");
$errors = array();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) // Checks that the submit button has been pressed.
{   
    $x = true;  
    if(!isset($_POST['password']) || $_POST['password'] === '') // Checks to make sure there is a message in the message box.
    {
        $x = false;
    array_push($errors, "** Please enter a password **");//Pushes an error
} else {
    $defaults['password'] = $_POST['password']; //stores the item, so we do not lose it if there is an error.
}
            if(!isset($_POST['username']) || $_POST['username'] === '') // Checks to make sure there is a message in the message box.
            {
                $x = false;
    array_push($errors, "** Please enter a username **");//Pushes an error
} else {
    $defaults['username'] = $_POST['username']; //stores the item, so we do not lose it if there is an error.
}
 }
 }
}
?>
<html> 
<head>
<title> Member's Only Page </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<h1> Please Sign In </h1>";
$userloginstuff = array("username" => "Username: ", "password" => "Password: ");
if($x === false){
foreach($errors as $error){ // goes through my errors and echos them in HTML.

 echo "<div class='error'> $error </div>";
}

  echo '<form action="" method="post">';

 foreach ($userloginstuff as $name => $label){

  echo "<div class = 'field'>",

 "<label for='$name'>$label</label>";
 echo "<input type='text' name='$name' id='$name' value=' '>";

}
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit'>";
}

echo"<br>";
echo "Don't have a username? <a href='Registration.php'> Click here.</a>"

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is horrible to read, space it properly with tabs.

I think your problem is that your login form is wrapped inside this:

```
if($x === false)
```

Try setting `$x = false;` when your login fails:

```
echo "Invalid username/password combination. Please try again.";
$_SESSION['logged'] = '0';
$x = false;
```